# Read a xml file from android UIatomator test case

Tags: android, android-uiautomator

I want to load test cases from a `xml` file to `UIatomator`.Then I will pass the xml file and generate the testcases on the fly. But I am unable to read the file. I tried`this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(resource);` 
to load the file but input stream becomes null.
How to read some file from `UIatomator` test case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is  how I got the input stream. Hope this will be useful for someone.

```
String file = "res/raw/<youfilename>.xml"; 
    InputStream ins = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(file);
```

Then this is yet another java input stream operation.